# How to open new bash terminal using Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, tkinter

I am trying to open a new terminal window in Tkinter application.
I've used os.system("/bin/bash") but it works in current bash only. Which stops runnning code and causes application freeze. I want to open new Terminal. How to do that? gedit like programs work fine without disturbing current apllication.

```
def openterm():
    os.system("/bin/bash")
def opengedit():
          os.system("/usr/bin/gedit")
menu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu = tk.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open Terminal", command=openterm)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open Gedit", command=opengedit)
```

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: `/bin/bash` is not a termimal; it's a shell that is often the program executed in a terminal.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for help! I ran ps command in terminal it shows bash as current running process. Thats why I though /bin/bash may open terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
os.system("x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/bash")
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exact.

Comment: Thank you so much, You are great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to explain it in code but I can point you in the right direction. Its an example from windows command prompt though. When you are in command prompt the way to open a new window is to type "start prompt" from the already open one. Maybe if you apply this same methodology to your script it will work. Hopefully I was of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this all you have to do is

os.system(exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator")

THAT'S IT FOLKS !!!